# Crashlytics - Enable Prompt -IOS

Tags: crashlytics

How does '**Always Send**' option after enabling prompt in Crashlytics work? Enabling the prompt feature will display a prompt with three options after crash on next launch- Send, Always Send and Don't send of which Always Send does not seem to work for me for ios
Do we need to provide some kind of implementation or it should work by default.

Comment: Paul from Crashlytics here. Please see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30493834/as-of-crashlytics-3-0-0-implementing-a-user-prompt-is-the-applications-respons.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply Paul, does that mean this 'Always Send' doesn't work, and  we will have to provide implementation of method below :
                                                       
(void)crashlyticsDidDetectReportForLastExecution:(CLSReport *)report completionHandler:(void (^)(BOOL submit))completionHandler;

Comment: Yes, unfortunately the crash dialog no longer works.